# Match if and switch statement while building PHP template engine (inspired from Laravel Blade)

Tags: php, regex, laravel-blade

I'm working on a small template engine inspired from Laravel Blade, but for some reason I couldn't match some directive patterns like `if` and `switch` statements.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do for `if` (I believe `switch` going to be similar):

```php
@if ($foo)
    <h1>Foo</h1>
@elseif ($bar)                // Existence 0 or more
    <h1>Bar</h1>
@else                         // Existence 0 or 1
    <h1>Baz</h1>
@endif
```

and the previous should be compiled as:

```php
<?php if ($foo) { ?>
    <h1>Foo</h1>
<?php } else if ($bar) { ?>   // Existence 0 or more
    <h1>Bar</h1>
<?php } else { ?>             // Existence 0 or 1
    <h1>Baz</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the Regex pattern I'm trying to achieve ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aDevMZ/1)):

```
(?:
    @(if)\s*
        (
            \(
                (?:
                    [^()]++|(?2)
                )+
            \)
        )\s*
        (
            [\s\S]*?
        )
){1}
(?:
    @(elseif)\s*
        (
            \(
                (?:
                    [^()]++|(?5)
                )+
            \)
        )\s*
        (
            [\s\S]*?
        )
)*?
(?:
    @(else)\s*
        (
            [\s\S]*?
        )
)??
\s*@(endif)
```

But unfortunately I couldn't match the full statement correctly.

This pattern is the best I can go so far, so any clue what is wrong?

Comment: I suppose instead of `if ($foo)` you could have some complex expression, like `if ("abc" . $foo . (34 + 40*$a) != $bar)`... You need to write a parser.

Comment: I think this part is going to catch any expression
`(?:[^()]++|(?2))+`
also I don't care about what is written inside, I care about the full expression to be matched.

Comment: I understand, but what if parentheses occur in a quoted string and they are not balanced? Your regex will not deal well with that. And that is just scratching the surface of all the things that can go wrong.

Comment: Now I got your point, but I was looking to keep it simple as possible, at least for the first stage.

Comment: Then you'll somehow complete that first stage, and when you need more complexity you'll have to trash it all and start again :). trincot is right, you need to write a parser, that'll be your first stage.

Comment: The `else` and `elsif` must always be followed with a whitespace, see https://regex101.com/r/aDevMZ/2

Comment: For some reason it matches only the last `elseif`, if there is many of them.